# WCF Server & TIBCO Client - Decrypt Digital Signing Web Service Soap Message

Tags: wcf, soap, sign, digital-certificate, tibco

I have created the WCF web service which uses messageprotectionorder as "SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature". I have also developed the .net client to consume this web service. I am able to successfully able to connect and receive response from my WCF web service. But, my client is trying to consume WCF web service from TIBCO java client where TIBCO does not have concept of "MessageProtectionOrder". The sample signed soap request is as follows

`<MessageLogTraceRecord>
    <HttpRequest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
    <Method>POST</Method>
    <QueryString></QueryString>
    <WebHeaders>
      <Connection>Keep-Alive</Connection>
      <Content-Length>7895</Content-Length>
      <Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
      <Expect>100-continue</Expect>
      <Host>comp118</Host>
      <SOAPAction>"https://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/APISIGN/IAPI/EnquireTransaction"</SOAPAction>
    </WebHeaders>
  </HttpRequest>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
      <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPowY5/i7l8ZdOl4B6x1uzACIAAAAA1re1c/La5kK2h1tnd2ijrMveD45HGZtHvanrpR7sXroACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-34291a98-4feb-43eb-8f91-f182297d086b-21">
          <u:Created>2013-06-17T07:16:53.671Z</u:Created>
          <u:Expires>2013-06-17T07:21:53.671Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <o:BinarySecurityToken>
          <!-- Removed-->
        </o:BinarySecurityToken>
        <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"></DigestMethod>
          </e:EncryptionMethod>
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <o:SecurityTokenReference>
              <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">wc18MSP1B9qEKFLe8ji4H5tlIHQ=</o:KeyIdentifier>
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
          </KeyInfo>
          <e:CipherData>
            <e:CipherValue>aQ4FENLuKcZvQGhiNPINr0c8BmTbCaLmXACs3ZFcsnRFVmGRMWUEIXCWCivJCxOIc9kYeftMxGADr6EbAJ6A3Bi/EcgLYnAulxZUcwMQrYwBTsbjFIOzJJBo9Ru5cz3RX+E/MgsroN9VFcOCzFfxlGiOi0ZmEqgfedzDlWBrRtUddA/mE9t6ZZBxsRDq1zzYu0bhY3oRtGe/RI0iYhZuAeS/UAk7g1PnIbr39lLI1XcYZG2gLGFlaxYGT76n+Zmph2tYW1usBnvHVXOpLc3Q8DN9CJ7lZJ8f+euTqIuDSApRLCHciauonQ6rPguPpSQQhLYf1CroqIeMr/nyStR0jQ==</e:CipherValue>
          </e:CipherData>
          <e:ReferenceList>
            <e:DataReference URI="#_2"></e:DataReference>
            <e:DataReference URI="#_3"></e:DataReference>
          </e:ReferenceList>
        </e:EncryptedKey>
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
          <e:CipherData>
            <e:CipherValue>+VJi2EwCmK4ovTULaBd+.....</e:CipherValue>
          </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
      </o:Security>
      <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://comp118/API_WCF_UAT/API.svc</To>
      <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://XXX.XXX.XX.XX/APISIGN/IAPI/EnquireTransaction</Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body u:Id="_1">
      <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>r0ktDG7sauaw7R2PEowODZFaC7Y5Gj3WWuctwOwiewZ.....</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedData>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>`

I would like to understand what values are signed and encrypted in the following tags

1. EncryptedKey tag -> CipherData -> CipherValue what value is
   encrypted here.
2. For Signature encryption, AES256/CBC algorithm is
   used.
3. What is the Key and IV value for AES algorithm? 3) Instead of
   "rsa-oaep encryption method" in request message, algorithm "rsa-1_5"
   can be used? If yes, where to specify this?

Kindly someone reply at the earliest.

Thanking You,

Bhavin Shah.

Comment: are you the client or the server? please publish a working envelope and what envelope you can generate in addition to the exception

Comment: I am working on the server side. The above mentioned envelope is working one. The consumer side is trying to connect using TIBCO. They don't have any messageprotectionorder as "SignBeforeEnryptAndEncryptSignature".

Comment: so your question is not about wcf but about TIBCO java client configuration, I suggest you reflect that in the title and tags to attract the right answers. unless you are willing to change your wcf service to it uses simpler security. In general you should never deal with IV, this is very low level, you should use a framework that abstracts that for you (e.g. Axis for java)

Comment: No sir, it is actually about WCF only. WCF generates random shared/session/transient key. This key is internally used by framework as IV for aes-256 algorithm and is encrypted with server certificate's public key. (Correct me if I am wrong). The clients need clarity on this front that how is this key generated? and how they can implement this. I have shared this link with for understanding on messageprotectionorder [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa967562(v=vs.90).aspx). what else links can be shared with them so, that they can understand the protectionorder better.

Comment: WCF uses standard WS-Security which java has some libraries that implement too

Comment: Can't we use custombinding with messageprotectionorder as "signbeforeencryptandencryptsignature" which can be consumed by java clients as well? our requirement is body and signature both should be signed and encrypted, that's why we have chosen this binding. How will the client be able to implement it?

Comment: you should use one of two approaches: a) someone who knows both ws-security and tibco web services client very well (I lack the second req) should build the client for this wcf service OR b) you need the client to generate the SOAP you want and then fine tune the WCF service to fit it. Currently I'm not sure if you're trying to understand how WCF work so java can consuem it, or you are trying to change wcf (and what soap format you want to have)